AWS Lake Formation/Redshift Integration with IAM IDC getting permission denied with everything except IAMAllowedPrincipals
I've been going down the AWS Lake Formation (LF) rabbit hole trying for days to get it to work with Redshift and IAM Identity Center (IAM IDC).
The intended goal:

User accesses external tables (glue catalog pointing to parquet files) via Redshift Serverless in QueryEditorV2
User logs into Redshift with an IAM IDC account that belongs to an IDC group. I followed the tutorial here very closely.
Access to tables is managed by AWS Lake Formation integrated with the IAM IDC. Followed this tutorial with apparent success for LF/IDC integration.

Before messing around with the new Lake Formation we had a functional data lake that can be queried in Redshift QueryEditorV2 using the normal federated users and JDBC user connections, the connections still work. I have managed to get Redshift integrated with our IDC and have a test user who is part of a group added to an IDC group which is also available to be assigned to tables and resources in AWS Lake Formation. When I log into the QueryEditorV2 with that user I was initially able to query tables which were made visible already before the LF work.
However, I've realized that I am only able to query the tables successfully when the table has LF permissions via the IAMAllowedPrincipals group. When this is revoked and I grant the permissions via either the IAM IDC user directly or the IAM IDC Group which the user belongs to I am unable to query. I get the below error message in QueryEditorV2:
ERROR: AwsClientException: AccessDeniedException from glue - Insufficient Lake Formation permission(s) on example_table[ErrorId: 1-66a178f2-00168194599db4c26280f923]
In short, it seems that my Redshift IDC user is authenticating with LF via the IAMAllowedPrincipals pathway to access data rather than Identity Center credentials. I won't list all the things I've tried here but I've spent a couple days going through the two tutorials I listed above as well as all other Lake Formation documentation which seemed useful. I've tried several combinations of LF permission settings, data location registration, hybrid access vs. no hybrid access and am just having a hard time understanding why the only permission set that seems to work for anything are the IAM roles which would have had access to the data lake anyways.

Ah this damn thing, had to go to aws support for it, doesn’t matter if ur an iam admin, u still need to go into the lake itself and specifically grant permissions to the user/role to access the data for that specific lake

Hi thanks! I actually have been in talks with AWS Support and after verifying my setup looked correct they were still stumped and have escalated the issue to LF internal experts. Still waiting on a response.
For clarification, when you say "go into the lake" do you mean you're granting IAM permissions on the buckets? I.e. not just LF permissions? Or are you talking about the granting permissions elsewhere?

Granting the permissions in LF itself, that’s the step I missed when setting it up

Finally figured this out after talking with AWS Support. Turns out that this is caused by a known bug regarding partitions on tables https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lake-formation/latest/dg/limitations.html#issue-table-partitions.
Unfortunately, it seems like this issue has been outstanding for years.
